# Nonlinear second order differential equation from finite differences

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm studying the catenary curve. I just obtained the following relation

$$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=a\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$$,

for a small piece of chain in equilibrium. Here, $s$ is a small portion, actually a line, which can be approximated to $\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$ (Pythagoras), and $\tan\theta=\Delta y/\Delta x$.

[image: Catenary]

What I want to do is to obtain the differential equation,

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=a\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$$,

from the first equation only.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equation_of_Catenary/Formulation_1/Proof